# MongoDB Aggregation regex match object id

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework, objectid

I have a collection;

```
  "users": [
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c4185be19da7e815cb18f59"),
  "name": "User1"
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c4185be19da7e815cb18f5a"),
  "name": "User2"
}  ]
```

I need to search users collection by regex.

```
db.results.aggregate([{
        "$match": {
            "name": {
                "$regex": "user",
                "$options": "si"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

this works for searching against user field. I tried with the below code to search against id. But it didn't work for me.

```
db.results.aggregate([{
        "$match": {
            "_id": {
                "$regex": "18f5a",
                "$options": "si"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The `_id` field is `ObjectId` type by default hence you can't regex match it.

If you're using Mongo version 4.0+ you can use [toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/).

```
db.results.aggregate([
      {
         $addFields: {
            _id: {$toString: "$_id"}
         }
     },
     {
        "$match": {
            "_id": {
                "$regex": "18f5a",
                "$options": "si"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I'm using MongoDB 3.6 :(

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not... , adding an `strId` field to your collection is the only other way to do it.

Comment: How to convert this query into spring boot?